# Qcustomplot Display coordinates of selected points using mouse event

Tags: qt, mouseevent, mouseover, qcustomplot

I need to display a set of points(nearly 200) on my custom plot. Thereafter when I click on a specific point ,it should display its coordinates using mouse event. The mouse event should be able to display only those points coordinates where I click and not the remaining empty region. I have tried using event->pos().x() to a pixeltocoord. But no use. I need a help in mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

Your question its a little vague, 'but not use' meaning what ? Did you received the event and the information is not useful ? or you never got an event ? Or the value is wrong for some perspective ? Is it your custom plot a QWidget ?
Well, I try anyway ...

If your custom plot is a QWidget:
First you need to enable Mouse tracking in your widget

```
CustomPlotWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Then you should store the coordinates in the mouse press event, you do that by overriding the event handler

```
CustomPlotWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   save_coords=event->pos;
}
```

Then when you paint the widget you use that coordinates to display some text there, or you can pop a QToolTip in that location (that is what I do, and it looks really nice)

According to your comment if you went with the solution of drawing yourself the coordinates you just need to redraw the section where you previously draw them. You can store the rectangular area when you draw before, then you redraw everything under that area but the coordinates.

```
CustomPlotWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   ...
   save_coords=event->pos;
   update(areaWhereYouPreviouslyDrawCoordinates);
   update(areaWhereYouWantToDrawNewCoordinates);
}
CustomPlotWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
...
   if (event->rect().insersect(areaWhereYouWantToDrawNewCoordinates))
   {
        drawCoordinates();
        areaWhereYouPreviouslyDrawCoordinates=areaWhereYouWantToDrawNewCoordinates;
   }
...
}
```

If you go with the solution using QToolTip:

```
CustomPlotWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   ...
   if (needToDrawCoordinates)
        QToolTip::showText(Where,Coordinates);
   else
        QToolTip::hideText();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pablo! Yes,I recieved the event.The problem from my side is ,I have to select a single point from a set of points and that specific point should display its coordinates and when I click on some other point,the previous coordinates should be disappeared and the current selected point’s coordinates  should be displayed.